# venv installing system wide pip packages into venv virtual environment in ansible

Tags: python, pip, ansible, virtualenv, python-venv

I am running ansible to install some pip packages into virtual environment using `venv` but its installing exact same version and no. packages from system wide python and not what is the mentioned in `requirement.txt`.

I am able to achieve success when i am doing it manually. i.e system wide pip packages and virtual environment pip packages are different.

I am getting below error in ansible

```
TASK [curator : Install pip packages List.] ****************************************************************************************************************************
fatal: [elasticsearch_1]: FAILED! => {
    "changed": false,
    "cmd": "/home/user/elk-venv/bin/pip list --format=freeze",
    "rc": 13
}

MSG:

[Errno 13] Permission denied
```

Steps i am doing through ansible task are -

1. Creating `venv` using command module as below

```
# /usr/bin/python3.6 -m venv /home/user/elk-venv
```

2. Copying `requirements.txt` file and `tranferred_packages` folder inside `/home/user/elk-venv/`.

`requirements.txt` has list of pip packages and `tranferred_packages` folder has downloaded packages. basically installing packages offline way.

3. Using pip module trying to install packages as below,

```
- name: Install pip packages List.
  pip:
    requirements: /home/user/elk-venv/requirements.txt
    extra_args: "--no-index --find-links=file:////home/user/elk-venv/tranferred_packages"
    virtualenv: /home/user/elk-venv
    virtualenv_python: /home/user/elk-venv/bin/python3.6
```

Below is the virtual environment created by ansible (elk-env)

Getting permission denied when trying with `bin/pip3 list`.

```
(elk-venv) [root@Server elk-venv]# bin/pip3 list
-bash: bin/pip3: Permission denied
```

able to list the pip3 list like below, but it seems to be copy of system python

```
(elk-venv) [root@Server elk-venv]# pip3 list
attrs (19.3.0)
blist (1.3.6)
```

If we see below it shows `/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages`.

```
(elk-venv) [root@Server elk-venv]# pip3 show pytz
Name: pytz
Version: 2019.3
Summary: World timezone definitions, modern and historical
Home-page: http://pythonhosted.org/pytz
Author: Stuart Bishop
Author-email: stuart@stuartbishop.net
License: MIT
Location: /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages
Requires:
(elk-venv) [root@Server elk-venv]#
```

Not sure why but config file also showing `/usr/bin`

```
(elk-venv) [root@Server elk-venv]# cat  pyvenv.cfg
home = /usr/bin
include-system-site-packages = false
version = 3.6.8
(elk-venv)
```

pip/python files under bin folder. `python3.6` is pointing to `/usr/bin/python3.6`

```
(elk-venv) [root@Server bin]# ls -lrth
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   18 Apr 28 21:56 python3.6 -> /usr/bin/python3.6
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root    9 Apr 28 21:56 python3 -> python3.6
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root    9 Apr 28 21:56 python -> python3.6
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  224 Apr 28 21:56 pip
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  224 Apr 28 21:56 pip3.6
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  224 Apr 28 21:56 pip3
```

files under `elk-venv` venv. Can't see `LICENSE` file here which is there in `devenv`.

```
drwxr-x--- 2 root root 4.0K Apr 28 21:56 include
-rw-r----- 1 root root   69 Apr 28 21:56 pyvenv.cfg
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root    3 Apr 28 21:56 lib64 -> lib
drwxr-x--- 3 root root 4.0K Apr 28 21:56 lib
drwxr-x--- 2 root root 4.0K Apr 28 21:56 bin
-rw-r----- 1 root root 1022 Apr 28 21:56 requirements.txt
drwxr-x--- 3 root root 4.0K Apr 28 21:56 tranferred_packages
```

Created below virtual environment manually (devenv) it has its own pip packages.

here able to list the packages. Not getting permission denied.

```
(devenv) [root@Server devenv]# bin/pip list
Package               Version
--------------------- ----------
APScheduler           3.6.3
attrs                 19.3.0
pip                   21.1
```

It shows package from its own path i.e `/root/devenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages`.

```
# pip3 show pytz
Name: pytz
Version: 2019.3
Summary: World timezone definitions, modern and historical
Home-page: http://pythonhosted.org/pytz
Author: Stuart Bishop
Author-email: stuart@stuartbishop.net
License: MIT
Location: /root/devenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages
Requires:
Required-by: tzlocal, twilio, APScheduler
```

config file is showing `/bin`.

```
(devenv) [root@Server devenv]# cat pyvenv.cfg
home = /bin
include-system-site-packages = false
version = 3.6.8
(devenv) [root@Server devenv]#
```

pip/python files under bin folder. here `python3.6` is pointing to `/bin/python3.6`.

```
(devenv) [root@Server bin]# ls -lrth
total 148K
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   14 Apr 27 17:39 python3.6 -> /bin/python3.6
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root    9 Apr 27 17:39 python3 -> python3.6
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root    9 Apr 27 17:39 python -> python3.6
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  233 Apr 28 12:29 pip3.6
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  233 Apr 28 12:29 pip3
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  233 Apr 28 12:29 pip
```

files under `devenv` venv.

```
-rw-r----- 1 root root   65 Apr 27 17:39 pyvenv.cfg
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root    3 Apr 27 17:39 lib64 -> lib
drwxr-x--- 3 root root 4.0K Apr 27 17:39 lib
drwxr-x--- 2 root root 4.0K Apr 27 17:39 include
-rw-r----- 1 root root  12K Apr 28 12:30 LICENSE
drwxr-x--- 3 root root 4.0K Apr 28 13:30 bin
drwxr-x--- 2 root root 4.0K Apr 28 20:45 tranferred_packages
-rw-r----- 1 root root 1022 Apr 28 20:45 requirements.txt
(devenv) [root@Server devenv]#
```

ansible version is - `ansible 2.9.9` 
ansible python version = 2.7.5

I think something missing in the pip module above in anisble causing this. Can someone please tell what it is?

Thanks,

Comment: above one works when we create `venv` inside `/root` but gives `permission denied` error when creating inside `/home/user/`. Even after using `become: true` for `virtualenv creation` task and `installing of pip packages` task it gives the same error.